# Java android ImageView with zoom

Tags: java, android, android-layout, zooming

I have been searching for a view that can handle this. What i want is to allow the users to zoom in/out of an image.
Right now i can not find any pre-built solutions for this except the `WebView`. One could argue that Google should actually offer this without having to resort to the `WebView` (That one limits the layout possibilities).
I would like to have the same built-in functionality like for `iPhones/iPads`.

So question is, what user-built views are there out that could handle pinch-zoom in/out of an image?

I have tested 2 different custom made solutions but neither worked as expected. One managed to re-size, but only in one direction at a time (either horizontally or vertically) and the other did not even work.

Update: It should be possible to use the solution with Android 2.3+. (Majority of the users are in that range)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found one very interesting few days ago. I think it's the best one I've seen. You can zoom with a double tap, pinch, has acceleration with movement, etc.

Take a look [here](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView).

Answer (score 1):

There are several Android view libraries that can handle what you are looking for.

Check out these

https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView 
http://code.google.com/p/android-pinch/ 
https://github.com/jasonpolites/gesture-imageview

Answer (score 0):

I achieved good results with this library: http://blog.sephiroth.it/2011/04/04/imageview-zoom-and-scroll/

It is not a total drop in replacement for imageview but it also works in a Viewpager where the Viewpager handles horizontal Swiping for page changes.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Android 3.0 (API Level 11) you can zoom every view using `setScaleX()`, `setScaleY()`, `setPivotX()`, `setPivotY()` etc., or just using `setMatrix()`.

Comment: I can't speak for the original poster but for me getting just 30% of the market wouldn't be acceptable: [Current Android version distribution](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html)